# Facebook Android sdk Game Request Dialog shows "Game Requests are only available to games"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-requests

I'm updating my android app to the latest Facebook SDK (4.0.0). When I create a GameRequestDialog, it shows me this message:  "Game Requests are only available to games", instead of showing my facebook friends. I was using WebDialog before in the older sdk and this didn't happen. I tried using WebDialog in sdk 4 but it still shows me this message.

UPDATE: here's the logcat output

```
{FacebookServiceException: httpResponseCode: -1, facebookErrorCode: 3405, facebookErrorType: null, message: Game Requests are only available to games.}
```

Comment: _Is_ your app in the Games category and does it have a working canvas implementation? Otherwise, you are not allowed to use invite requests. Alternatives are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set your Facebook app as a game [category](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/categories), in the [App settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/). 
Otherwise, you can't use `GameRequestDialog`, because your app is not a game. In this case, Facebook gives you [`AppInviteDialog`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android).

Comment: +1 even though my app is a web app, but this answers helped me a lot after hours of digging. the app-invites dialog keep opening and closing without any useful info. when i try in chrome i got the error log , thank you